# How to seamlessly display scraped web page which has intermittent updates

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display a web page in kiosk mode on a 1080p monitor showing "what's on". The data can be scraped from an existing web page (which I don't control). It must then be displayed with some new formatting (background image, no scroll bars, new header and footer).

The original web page is updated at infrequent intervals. I am happy for my page to update every 15 minutes or so. My page should maximise the fonts to display as large as possible (and reduce the font on any overflow).

This is all being done on a Raspberry Pi Zero so horsepower is limited.

I am currently scraping the original web page using a perl program scheduled with cron. This program extracts the relevant table of data and adds new header and footer. To try to make the change seamless, my web page includes this new page as an iframe - actually two iframes that it swaps between so the rendering is invisible:

```
<body onload="load(); update();">
    <h1>What's on this week</h1>
    <div id="floating-div">
        <iframe src="iframe.html" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;" id="if1"></iframe>
        <iframe src="iframe.html" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;" id="if2"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>

function update() {
    if1 = document.getElementById("if1");
    if2 = document.getElementById("if2");
    if (if1.style.display == "none") {
        if1.style.display = "block";
        if2.style.display = "none";
        if2.src = "iframe.html";
    } else {
        if2.style.display = "block";
        if1.style.display = "none";
        if1.src = "iframe.html";
    }
}

function load() {
    setInterval(update, 15000);
}
```

The iframe.html page (created by perl) is:

```
<body onload="set_size();">
    <div class="cdiv">
        <table id="calendar" class="weekly">
...
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am struggling on how to adjust the font size dynamically in the set_size() function. I can adjust the size on the visible iframe but this doesn't work on the one loading while invisible. The function I am using to detect overflow is:

```
function check(el) {
    var curOverf = el.style.overflow;
    if (!curOverf || curOverf === "visible")
        el.style.overflow = "hidden";
    var isOverflowing = el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth ||
        el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight;
    el.style.overflow = curOverf;
    return isOverflowing;
}
```

How can I do this seamless display update with dynamic font sizing?

Apologies for the long post but I wanted to explain the whole problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I gave up on my original approach. I have now re-written the perl program to implement a Web Socket server which scrapes the web site every 15 minutes. If there is a change in the scraped data, it sends it to any connections.

The javascript in the local web page receives this data via a web socket and replaces the table that it had with the new table. The font resize routine then runs as before. Since the page is visible, it works as intended.

The downside is that this update will be visible. However, updates for the current week are infrequent so this is acceptable.